# Oracle Apex Tree Selected Node not working

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i've a basic tree region on my apex page. The Attribute "Selected Node Page Item" is set to a text input on the same page.

When I a select a tree element the defined text input remains empty.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle APEX  help about 'Selected Node Page Item' :
"Select the page or application item that you wish to hold the selected node value. You can type in the name or pick from the list of available items.

This item is used to save tree state, by holding the value of the last selected node. The value of the selected node can be saved to the selected item via the node link attribute, or via a page process. When the tree is reloaded, the tree is opened to the selected node value."

So just setting this attribute wont get value there. You have to use some method (like link attribute of the tree)to store value to the item . The use of 'Selected Node Page Item' is to hold the session state value of the tree node so that if you navigate to some other page and come back to the tree page, the tree will  open to the ''Selected Node Page Item' value instead of showing a fresh tree.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. How does the link attribute oft three works?

Comment: This is the help text for tree definition:

Comment: If u check the help text for tree definition you will find a line like, 'null as link'.  Instead of 'null' , you can call a java-script function (define the js function  in the 'function and global variable declaration' space in the page properties) there and pass the value to be stored as an argument.

Comment: For example, if you want to store 'empId' of the selected node to a pageitem,  use 'javascript:pageItemValue('''||empId||''')' AS LINK' in the tree definition. Then define function pageItemValue(node)  
{  
    $s('P1_NODE', node);  
}
in the 'function and global variable declaration' area in the page properties ,if you want to get the empId of the selected node in P1_NODE  page item.

Comment: Thanks @Madona. I tried adding js function and it works.

Answer (score 1):

To set the value of a PAGE ITEM called P1_SELECTED_NODE_ID on click, add the following `LINK` column in the SELECT statement of your query:

```
SELECT
  NODE_ID,
  NODE_DISPLAY,
  PARENT_NODE_ID,
  'javascript:$s("P1_SELECTED_NODE_ID","' || NODE_ID || '")' LINK
FROM MY_TABLE
```

and then set the LINK column to `LINK` in the tree attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the page item need to be Display-Only, rather than a Text Input?  Why would you allow someone to edit the value you're pushing the Selected Node Page Item?

Comment: I need the the value in a protected hidden input to create a master-detail view. Only for test purposes i use a text field. So I can see the current value on the first view.